# django cannot import models from directory under app

Tags: python, django

I have dir structure like below picture. I would like to import models in thumbnail dir. However, I cannot get models. It just throw syntax invalid.

**I am trying to import models.py in WebtoonServer from thumbnail/thumbnail.py**

```
from WebtoonServer.models # models.py is in WebtoonServer dir
```

[image]

I tried this as well

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))

from WebtoonServer.models
```

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'WebtoonServer',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

Comment: Where were you importing the models? And what is exact import statement you used. In your question you just mentioned `from WebtoonServer.models` but it should be `from WebtoonServer.models import *` to import all models or `from WebtoonServer.models import <ModelName>` to import particular model.

Comment: Yeah, if i try that one, I get this error  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WebtoonServer'

Comment: What are the files in the parent `webtoon` directory?  Where is your manage.py?

Comment: Where is your 'models.py' file? In thumbnail dir , if then you need to create `__init__.py` file also and use `from models import <modelsName>`.

Comment: Where were you importing the models? And where is your models.py

Comment: "# models.py is in WebtoonServer dir"

Comment: manage.py is in webtoon( root ) and models.py is in WebtoonServer as described in question

Comment: Can you show setings.INSTALLED_APPS please

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS Added

Comment: can you give the location or file in which you are importing the models?

Comment: I am trying to import models.py in WebtoonServer from thumbnail/thumbnail.py -- I think you reversed your usage of models. Is that import models in thumbnail/thumbnail.py?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just say where you're importing from, but not what you're importing, they both have to be specified.

Have you tried `from WebtoonServer.models import <Class Name>`??

I think this is most likely related to your setup, the above code should definitely work, and has worked on proper Django setups.

I suggest having a read here:
http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Describes some issues that may arise with wrong structure. I see your "manage.py" is in WebtoonServer.

Comment: Then, I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WebtoonServer'

Answer (score 0):

if for example you have Class1 in app1.modles
and Class2 in app2.models
the error throws when your try to import Class1 into app2.models
and mistakenly try to import Class2 into app1.models